# Manifest file prevents full screen on ios

Tags: ios, webpack, playframework, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I develop a web app with VueJs as frontend and playframework with SCALA as backend.

When I prepare the app for production mode, I run:

npm run build & sbt compile stage

and then start it with sbt start the production mode. I have the following problem.

In iOS, FullScreen (PWA) is no longer possible. But it was already possible in development mode.

My index. html looks like this:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    
    
    <meta content="minimum-scale=1,width=device-width,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" name="viewport"><!--[if IE]><link rel="icon" href="./logo_klein.jpg"><![endif]-->
    <title>EXAMPLE</title>
    <link href="./static/css/app.f87699ad.css" rel="preload" as="style">
    <link href="./static/css/chunk-vendors.5c682f89.css" rel="preload" as="style">
    <link href="./static/js/app.7150a234.js" rel="preload" as="script">
    <link href="./static/js/chunk-vendors.be075eb5.js" rel="preload" as="script">
    <link href="./static/css/chunk-vendors.5c682f89.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./static/css/app.f87699ad.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./img/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./img/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <!--<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">-->
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#4DBA87">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="hoScom">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="./img/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#4DBA87">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="./img/icons/msapplication-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">
</head>
```

and my manifest. json so

```
{
"name":"EXAMPLE",
"short_name":"EX",
"start_url":"http://myUrl/",
"display":"standalone",
"scope":"http://myUrl/"
}
```

If I remove the maniffest. json from index. html I can start the app Fullscreen and Standalone once I have added it to the main screen.

Unfortunately I need the manifest file because I have to give it the start_url and scope.

Does anyone know the problem and can help me?

**++UPDATE++**

I found out now, he can not read the manifestfile, as you can see at the screenshot. There is the error in console, Application window (firefox) and my folder structure.

[image]

Is the way wrong as i import the manifest? Could it be a problem with the playframework, or is it definitely a frontend problem? Or maybe a problem from vue webpack?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `/` for your `Start_URL` & `Scope`; also: `manifest.webmanifest` not `manifest.json`. The latter is within spec, but iOS seems to prefer `.webmanifest.`

Comment: I changed the name to .webmanifest and   "start_url":"/", and "scope":"/"

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work... When i remove the manifest the app starts in fullscreen. i don´t get it...